# как правильно вывести записи?

Tags: mysql

Таблица:

```
id|status|last_online_time
1 |online|1433635177  // 23:59
2 |offline|1433635220 // 00:00
тд
----------------------------
```

нужно вывести записи по последнему онлайну, но чтобы онлайн записи были вначале.

Если `order by last_online_time desc` - порядок есть, но в текущем варианте первая будет offline
Если `order by status='online' desc` - первая будет онлайн, но порядка по последнему онлайну нет.

Как решить?

Comment: Кто мешает указать два критерия сортировки в `order`? `ORDER BY a,b`, `ORDER BY a DESC, b ASC` и т.д. P.S. Старайтесь не игнорировать документацию по используемым инструментам. Там много чего полезного есть.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно нужна сортировка по двум критериям. Они перечисляются через запятую в порядке снижения приоритета:

```
… ORDER BY (status='offline') ASC, last_online_time DESC
```

Выражение сравнения дает результат 1 или 0. Сортировка ASC, т.е. ноли идут раньше единиц, а 'online' даст нам 0. Затем сортируем по дате-времени в обратном порядке, т.е. самые недавние будут раньше.
Итого:

- онлайн свежие
- онлайн давние
- оффлайн свежие
- оффлайн давние

Экспериментируйте с порядком и ASC|DESC чтобы добиться нужного результата.